# In ASP.Net C#, on button click event I find the FileUpload Control within DataList and It gives error?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the Error:

> - Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

This error is found when for each process tries to find the items.

```
 protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      foreach (DataListItem item in this.ImageRepeater.Items)
      {
           FileUpload fup = (FileUpload)ImageRepeater.FindControl("ImageUpload");
           if (fup.HasFile)
           {
               updateImageChanges();
               divTopImageCheckChangedmessage.Visible = false;
            }
      }         
   }
```

My requirement is that I want to satisfy the check if there is no file loaded into Fileupload control within ASP.Net DataList then not to allow, the `updateImageChanges();` function to be hit.

I will be grateful to you all.

Comment: Please provide the source of `uploadImageChanges`.

Comment: As the error states,you are not suppose to modify the ImageRepeater.Items collection inside the for each.I suspect you are modifying the collection inside the updateImageChanges().

Comment: uploadImageChanges() is the function where I execute the procedures to update the data.

Answer (score 0):

Since updateImageChanges() doesn't take a parameter, I assume it iterates through your repeater items again? How does it know what item to work with? Whatever your are doing in that function (since you did not post the code for it) is the source of your error, it is not in the code you posted. However, this solution will work for you:

You can update that function to take a parameter (say a FileUpload control) and then pass that from your if statement to the updateImageChanges() method. That way this method will ONLY update changes, and not need to loop through your repeater items again to get what it needs.

Something like this:

```
  protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      foreach (DataListItem item in this.ImageRepeater.Items)
      {
           FileUpload fup = (FileUpload)ImageRepeater.FindControl("ImageUpload");
           if (fup.HasFile)
           {
               updateImageChanges(fup);
               divTopImageCheckChangedmessage.Visible = false;
            }
      }         
   }

   private void updateImageChanges(FileUpload fup)
   {
       // remove your code that loops through to get to the correct file upload
       // leave code that works with current fup and use passed parameter instead of the repeater items collection
   }
```

Comment: Thank you friends, let me make few changes, then I'll provide you the updateImageData(), or let you know the current state. Regards – Jahan Zeb

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are looping through the DataList Items ,I think your code may look something like this :

Check this sample code for

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    DataListItem di = btn.NamingContainer as DataListItem;
    FileUpload fu = di.FindControl("fu") as FileUpload;       
    if (fu.HasFile)
    {
     // save to the database :


    }


}
```

I think this error is your  updateImageData call method gave

Comment: Thank you friends, let me make few changes, then I'll provide you the updateImageData(), or let you know the current state. Regards